# How can I use roc_auc_score() with the max_fpr parameter as the cross_val_score() scoring function?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, roc

I tried using `sklearn.metrics.make_scorer` with the `auroc_with_maxfpr` function I wrote, and I did a sanity check by comparing the result of that scorer with `max_fpr=1` vs the default `roc_auc` scorer to make sure it works. (`max_fpr` will be smaller than 1 in the actual use case). But the two `cross_val_score` calls return very different results. Any idea why?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.metrics import make_scorer, roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, KFold
import numpy as np

y_true = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1]
X = np.random.rand(len(y_true), 10)
kf = KFold(n_splits=2)
model = LogisticRegression(solver = 'lbfgs')

def auroc_with_maxfpr(y_true, y_score, **kwargs):
    return roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, max_fpr=1)
my_scorer = make_scorer(auroc_with_maxfpr)

scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y_true, cv=kf, scoring=my_scorer)
print(scores)

scores = cross_val_score(model, X, y_true, cv=kf, scoring='roc_auc')
print(scores)
```

Comment: Please [reprex]

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov Done! I'd appreciate your response!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add these parameters to make_scorer():
needs_prob = True, needs_threshold = True

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html